# Previous Button on Slideshow Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with my previous button for my slideshow. My next button works just fine but everytime I press previous it does a kind of shuffle mode and retrieves the pictures in a random order. If anyone could please help that would be great! I'm fairly new to JavaScript so please be patient and clear.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <nav class="clearfix">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="slide.html">Before/After</a></li>
                    <li><a href="fac.html">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <p id="menu">Menu</p>

            <div class="site-wrapper">
                <div class="header">
                    <a><div class="menu-trigger" title="Menu"></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </nav>

        <a href="home.html"><img src="img/logoBRB.png"/></a>

        <h1>Brad's Auto Body</h1>

        <p id="quote"><i>"Dedicated To Perfection"</i></p>
    </header>

    <section class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
        <figure>
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/corengine.jpg" width="100%">
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/corseat.jpg" width="100%">
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/blah.jpg" width="100%">
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/blah2.jpg" width="100%">
        </figure>
        <figure class="show">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/cor.jpg" width="100%">
        </figure>

        <span class="prev">&laquo;</span> <span class="next">&raquo;</span>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="social">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Brads-Auto-Body-475978275798070/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" id="fa"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <p>&copy;Copyright 2016. Brad’s Auto Body. All Rights Reserved.</p>

        <p>Web Design by<img class="logo" src="img/logoJJC.png">JJC Web Developers</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="slideshow.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var counter = 0, // to keep track of current slide
    $items = $('.slideshow figure'), // a collection of all of the slides, caching for performance
    numItems = $items.length; // total number of slides

// this function is what cycles the slides, showing the next or previous slide and hiding all the others
var showCurrent = function() {
    var itemToShow = Math.abs(counter % numItems); // uses remainder (aka modulo) operator to get the actual index of the element to show  
    $items.removeClass('show'); // remove .show from whichever element currently has it
    $items.eq(itemToShow).addClass('show');
};

// add click events to prev & next buttons 
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    showCurrent();
    counter++;
});

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
    showCurrent();
    counter--;
});

// if touch events are supported then add swipe interactions using TouchSwipe https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin
var $el = $('#slideshow');
$el.slideshow({
    duration: 400,
    delay: 3000,
    selector: '> img',
    transition: 'push(up)',
    autoPlay: true,
    show: function(params) {
        var nextIndex = params.next.index;
        if (nextIndex > 2) {
            // do something awesome when the slide is after the third slide.
        }
    },
    complete: function(params) {
        // do something awesome when a transition finishes
    }
});

// get the slideshow object if you want it
var slideshow = $el.data('slideshow');

// show the third slide
$el.slideshow('show', 2); // Element API
slideshow.show(2); // object API
// show the next slide
slideshow.show('next');
// pause and play
slideshow.stop();
slideshow.play();
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow {
    background-color: solid transparent;
    padding: 0;
}

.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    width: auto;
}

.show {
    transition: opacity 2s;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 110%;
}

.mySlides {
    height: 500px;
}

figure {
    transition: opacity 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}

.next, .prev {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: -.75em;
    opacity: .3;
    user-select: none;
}

.next:hover, .prev:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}

.next {
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px 5px 15px 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.prev {
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 15px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt, and depending on that i may or may not able to help you out. The doubt is that when the first image is being displayed , then the value of counter is 0 or 1.? Basically, are you keeping the current slide's value in the counter variable or the next slide's value?

Comment: I'm fairly new to JavaScript so I just used reference code but I believe that I have it at 0 as defined on line 1 of the JavaScript. @AnkushRaghuvanshi

Comment: if your counter has the index value of the current image in the items list, then according to me both the next and previous won't work properly. Coz your code has started with counter value as 0, so now when you press next, it removes the **show** class from the div which is being displayed right now and adds **show** class to that element in the **items** list whose index `value = Math.abs(counter % numItems)`, which in the very first case will be 0 only, even after clicking next. And only after you've clicked next twice, will the 2nd image be displayed. Is this happening in your case???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im really not sure how your slider even works by selecting the `figure` using modulo. I would suggest you to keep track of the `figure` element that has the `show` class and change the counter based on that.

First, when Javascript is loaded, you should set the `counter` variable to the index of the `figure` which has the `show` class. This can be achived with the following function (or just add it straigth to the variable declaration):

```
function getShowIndex() {
    return $('#slideshow figure').index($('.show'));
}
```

Then, change to next or previous image by adding or subtracting from the `counter`. Though, there are two exceptions:

1. When going from the **last** image to the **first** the `counter` value should be changed to `0`.
2. Likewise from the **firt** to the **last** the `counter` value should be changed to `[ammount of figure elements] - 1` aka index of the last `figure` element.

This can be achieved by somethin like this:

```
// Remove .show from whichever element currently has it and place it to
// figure that has index 'counter'
function showCurrent() {
    $items.removeClass('show');
    $items.eq(counter).addClass('show');
}

function showNext() {
    if (counter == numItems - 1) {
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        counter++;
    }

    showCurrent();
}

function showPrev() {
    if (counter == 0) {
        counter = numItems - 1;
    } else {
        counter--;
    }

    showCurrent();
}

// Add click events to prev & next buttons 
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    showNext();
});

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
    showPrev();
});
```

> ### [Minimal JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s10xtLmr/4/)
>
> I removed TouchSwipe from the demo as its implementation didn't seem to be finished.

**On a side note**: you seem to have two versions of `jQuery`, 2.2.1 and 2.1.3. Consider removing the latter and placing all of your JS files at the end of `body` tag. This way the JS files are loaded last. The order of the files also matters, it should be:

1. `jQuery`
2. `jQueryUI`
3. `TouchSwipe`
4. Your own files

Comment: Thank you so much! @V-Kopio